# Laravel realrashid/sweetalert not working

Tags: php, laravel, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am trying to install SweetAlert in my Laravel project so I ran this commands

```
composer require realrashid/sweet-alert

php artisan sweetalert:publish
```

And inside my controller I made this

```
public function handleIcityNewCairoInterest(Request $request)
{
    $first_name = $request->first_name;
    $last_name = $request->last_name;
    $email = $request->email;
    $phone = $request->phone;
    $project = $request->project;
    $unit = $request->unit;
    $budget = $request->budget;
    $installment = $request->installment;

    IcityNewcairoInterest::create([
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'project' => $project,
        'unit' => $unit,
        'budget' => $budget,
        'installment' => $installment
    ]);
    Alert::success('Success', 'Done!');
    return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

But when I submit the form it navigates me to the home page without pop up any alerts

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Hello, i believe you are using that library wrong. Write more about your function, i see that its fair to see blank page, because you are not returning view nor json response if ajax, neither redirecting user to other page as a result. Thus, you need to clarify, when the function is being called (ajax or else), if not ajax which view file should see user, considering it should redirect to somewhere. The flow of your code bynow is like get all coming data from request and store it, thats all, nothing happens after.

Comment: @tokkerbaz I modified the code and return to a view

Comment: now, if you are using redirect, then alert won't work. I'll write an answer now, to how solve that

Answer (score 1):

Alert won't work for you because of redirection. You can send data to your redirect route. So, on your return redirect line add `with()` function and send some data like:

```
return redirect(route('home'))->with('success', 'Done!');
```

and after that in your view file of homepage, because you are redirecting to your home. add this:

```
@if (\Session::has('success'))
   @php alert()->success('Success', \Session::get('success')); @endphp
@endif
```

Also, you may call `alert` function in your controller, on your homepage's function, (f.e pretending that your homepage's controller named `getHomepage`):

```
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;

public function getHomepage()
{
... //The rest of your functions code

   if (\Session::has('success')){
      alert()->success('Success', \Session::get('success'));
   }

... //The rest of your functions code
}
```

Hope it will help, i didn't test it out

Comment: I got this error htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, RealRashid\SweetAlert\Toaster given

Comment: @OsamaAmr, sorry, i updated answer. Try to use `@php alert()->success('Success', \Session::get('success')); @endphp` instead of `{{ alert()->success('Success', \Session::get('success')); }}`